# C++ Is it possible to create a std::list of type T when a constructor is required for type T?

Tags: c++, stl, std, stdlist

For example:

```
class apple
{
public:
    string name;

    apple::apple(string name) : name(name)
    {
    }
};
```

If I want to make a bunch of lists each with the type of apple, I thought I could do something like `std::list<apple> empire("empire"), macintosh("macintosh")`. Basically I want to pass arguments for a constructor of class T declared by `list<T>` when I'm creating a list. Sorry if I'm not explaining this right, feel free to edit my question if you have that ability.

Thanks

**EDIT This question seems to be confusing and it's probably because I gave a bad example. I need to redesign my class.** Following this example though what I wanted is a list that is all empire apples and each apple in that list has a designated type of empire, and a list that is all macintosh apples and each apple in that list has a designated type of macintosh.

So to clarify some or confuse some more here we go.

```
class apple
{
public:
    string variety_name;
    string description;
    apple::apple(string variety_name, string description)
        : variety_name(variety_name), description(description)
    {
    }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Vlad from Moscow's answer
    std::list<apple> empire(1, apple("empire", "picked yesterday")),
        macintosh(1, apple( "macintosh", "picked yesterday")); 

    // Vaughn Cato's answer
    empire.push_back(apple("empire", "picked today"));
    macintosh.push_back(apple("macintosh", "picked today"));

    for(list<apple>::iterator it=empire.begin(); it != empire.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << it->variety_name << " " << it->description << endl;
    }

    for(list<apple>::iterator it=macintosh.begin(); it != macintosh.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << it->variety_name << " " << it->description << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So as you can see it would be easier to store the variety once rather than each time; my class obviously needs a redesign but that doesn't make the answers any less valid. Everyone thanks for your help

Comment: You need at least copy constructors, and (in C++11) move constructors too.

Comment: `std::list<apple> empire` creates a list of apples called "empire".  Did you intend for empire to be a list of apples or just a single apple?

Comment: @Vaughn Empire to be a list of empire apples

Comment: @test: After `std::list<apple> empire("empire")`, are you expecting `empire` to be a list of apples containing a single apple with the name "empire"?

Comment: Info regarding the apple empire: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_%28apple%29

Comment: @Vaughn It's just the example I chose, maybe it's confusing. I have some empire apples, some macintosh apples, etc. I want those empire apples in one list, and macintosh apples in a separate list.

Comment: @test: From your example, it seems like you are wanting to associate the name with the list instead of with the individual apples in the list, even though the name is part of the apple, so I'm trying to understand your expectations.

Comment: Side note: Searching 'apple macintosh' in the web is misleading

Comment: @Vaughn This is my fault I made a bad example. Thanks for your help, I've marked an answer correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++11 you may use an initializer-list:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // C++11 initializer-list
    std::list<std::string> species = { "empire", "macintosh" };


    // Without C++11: You may initialize with an array:
    const char* species_array[] = { "empire", "macintosh" };
    std::list<std::string> species_list(
        species_array,
        species_array + sizeof(species_array)/sizeof(species_array[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

With apples it is:

```
int main() {
    // C++11 initializer-list
    std::list<apple> species = { apple("empire"), apple("macintosh") };


    // Without C++11: Initialize with an array:
    const apple species_arry[] = { apple("empire"), apple("macintosh") };
    std::list<apple> species_list(
        species_arry,
        species_arry + sizeof(species_arry)/sizeof(species_arry[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I was only able to use the `Without C++11` method but it works.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, you can use [`emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace), [`emplace_front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_front) and [`emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back) to construct object in-place with appropriate constructor:

```
std::list<apple> list;
list.emplace(list.end(), "one");
list.emplace_front("two");
list.emplace_back("three");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
std::list<apple> a;
a.push_back(apple("delicious"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
apple(string name);
```

is a so-called conversion constructor. It converts an object of type std::string to an object of type apple. It can be called implicitly by the compiler when it is awaiting an object of type aoole but gets an object of type std::string.

You could not do so if you would declare the constructor as explicit. For example

```
explicit apple(string name);
```

In this case your would need explicitly to specify the constructor. For example

```
std::list<apple> empire( 1, apple( "empire" ) );
```

Comment: @test It cannot work, there is [no constructor in `std::list<A>` that takes just an `A` as param](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list).

Comment: @test I am sorry but I do not know what code you compiled. At least your class definition contains an error. The constructor definition shall not have a qualified name. That is instead of testapple::apple(string name) : name(name) {} must be apple(string name) : name(name) {}  though some constructors as MS VC++ allows to use qulified name. Also I have a typo. Add the secon argument 1. I uodated my post.

Comment: @Johan Thanks. it was a typo. At first I thought about push_back but forgot to change the code.

Comment: Vlad I was able to compile after your edit that added the `1`, can you tell me why that works? Dieter had a working answer before you so I marked his as correct already.

Comment: I though that I descibed all in my post. What exactly do you do not understand?

Comment: I understand it missing was a typo, but I do not understand what it is doing there. What does the 1 mean?

Comment: Oh, now it is clear. It is a general constructor for most standard containers the first parameter of which specifies how many elements you are going to add to the container and the second parameter specifies an initial value which will be assigned to the elements. For example if you want to add in a list 10 integers that all have value 5 you could write std::list<int> l( 10, 5 );

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I recognize what you are talking about. Thanks again

Comment: what's that `apple(string name) : name(name);` ? it's not a valid C++

Comment: @Abyx It is a typo due to copy and paste. I uodated the post.

Comment: why don't you also fix all other typos

Comment: Where are there other typos?